# How To Store & Fetch A List in the Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I want to be able to define/mark a part of the page as a **repeated region** to bind to the records of a database table. *How and where should it be done?* In **document type** or in a **view**?

I know that I should put the logic in my template. But let me clarify what I want to do.

I want to:

1. Store a list of movies in the database using an entry form.
2. Fetch the list of movies and display it in the page.

I don't want to use JQuery, AngularJS etc., but rather to do it on the server side.

Comment: You want to mark/set a part of your Content with a language?

Answer (score 1):

As dampee says, it sounds like it might be worth reading up on a few general Umbraco tutorials first before solving this problem if you have the time, It will ultimately save you time later.  It seems like what you really need is a bit of background.

Document types are simply a description of the attributes and properties of the particular type of page that you would like to include in your website.

As an example of what I mean, consider a news article:

A news article may have have the following attributes defined in the document type: "article title", "article date", "article content".  A web site will contain many news article pages, but each of these will typically make use of only one news article document type.

For each news item you add to the website, you would add a new node of this document type to the content tree and complete the "article title", "article date", "article content" fields.

Document types have absolutely nothing to do with defining logic for presenting information.

When it comes to presenting information, you then associate a your document type with a template(s). Templates are basically asp.net Masterpages to which you add HTML content.  If you want to add dynamic content to a page beyond regurgitating text field data (such as adding a repeater bound to your data source or equivalent).  You will need to investigate adding user controls, you can either do this using standard .NET .ascx user controls or by adding Razor script files (I'd advise using the latter as its a much, much faster to write / cleaner approach).

These can then be added as macros in the back office in the developer section and then called from the HTML for your templates using the relevant tags, e.g.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <umbraco:Macro Alias="SomeAliasForYourMacro" runat="server"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

There are several other methods of doing this, but this is the one I prefer, I am also not sure how this applies to the MVC approach to developing Umbraco.  Still, there should be plenty to Google here.

Answer (score 0):

A documentType is a definition of a document which will be stored in your content tree.  A view (or a template as it is called in Umbraco) is a way to assemble data in HTML to be able to send it to the user.

If you want to repeat document (e.g. multiple pages under one page), then you have different documents (in the content tree) of some document type.

If you want to render those documents, then you do a foreach in a View.

If you are not sure, try the getting started documentation on http://our.umbraco.org.  That is the community site of Umbraco.